# Understanding flash file system wear in append mode

Tags: c++, c, file-io, filesystems, embedded

I have to write to an ever-growing log file on a flash device (MMC card), and I'm concerned about flash wear.

Let's say I use `fopen` or `std::ofsteam::open` to open a log file in write/append mode. That file is currently 10MB in size. If I only keep appending to the file, can I be assured that the file system will not try to re-write any of the previous 10MB into new flash blocks?

If that's not clear, I can ask the same question in a different way. Consider this scenario:

1. Create a new file named "log.txt"
2. Append 10kB to the file
3. Close the file
4. Other processes write to different files on the same disk/partition
5. Reopen "log.txt"
6. Append another 10kB to the file
7. Close the file

Does this have the same effect (in terms of flash wear) as this scenario:

1. Create a new file named "log.txt"
2. Append 20kB to the file
3. Close the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most flash file systems will have built-in wear leveling systems, so that the same section of flash isn't used over and over again.

And appending shouldn't be a problem as (I hope) the will not "wear" on writing new data when it stores the information - you only get wear on "erase" cycles, which only happens when you delete the file [and the sectors the file was in needs to be rewritten with new data - no point in erasing the content if it's not going to be replaced].

And to answer your actual question, it is better to use append mode than to write another new file. At least you are not "wearing" the part of the file that has already been written - and fragmentation shouldn't be a problem when it comes to flash - it takes exactly the same amount of time to access byte 0, 1, 1000 and 10000000000000, rather than a old-style hard-drive where a mechanical head has to move to get to the next block of data every few reads, and longer moves take longer to do.

Comment: If I understand correctly, fragmentation would occur if another file were created or modified before my log file grew enough to need another block. Is this correct?

Comment: I sure hope that a flash file-system doesn't erase the entire sector that has parts of two or more parts of a file in it, so that it can write more to one of those to files - that would be rather daft. The "right" solution is to let the file continue in another place - files don't need to be consecutive on the disk/SSED [as far as I know, except for boot sectors, but logfiles aren't boot sectors, so we should be safe from that].

Comment: To clarify, what I mean by fragmentation isn't a problem is that there is no particularly large penalty for have a fragmented file in flash - that's a problem for spinning disks that have movable heads, because the head has to move to get to the right part of the disk, and that gets slow if the file is scattered here, there and erverywhere on the disk. But flash, it makes little difference where the files are, it takes the same amount of time to read a block in one place as it does to read that same block should have been somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, I understand that there's no seek time involved in flash devices. I was just curious about when fragmentation would occur in my scenario. :)

Comment: It will be more fragmentation in the sense of "file does not live in consecutive blocks" if you append, but much less wear. And since fragmentation is a small factor, and wear is a big one, I know which I'd go for.

Comment: By the way, I don't know what flash devices are in the MMC you are using, but the ones I used to work with from AMD were (guaranteed to be) able to take 100K erase cycles. That's a lot of writes to one sector.  100K times 10M of logfile is 1TB of logging (and that's if all the blocks go to the same place every time, without any wear levelling algorithms)

Comment: If the 1TB figure holds up, I should be good for roughly 10000 years at the rate and quantity of data I'm logging. I'd like for archeologists to be able to use my device.

Comment: Well, I guess even if I'm off by a factor of 10 or 100, it won't make that much of a difference... ;)

Answer (score 1):

> If I only keep appending to the file, can I be assured that the file system will not try to re-write any of the previous 10MB into new flash blocks?

This depends on the flash file system.  Contrary to your desire, it is actually good on occasion to re-write some of the previous 10MB.  That is, to perform wear leveling.  Each flash chip has a **sector** and **erase block** size.  These play into the dynamics of *wear leveling*.  Each **erase block** has a maximum amount of cycles over a life time.  If your 10MB file is in nearly full flash, it makes sense to move some of the sectors so that new *erases* can take place there.  This is called *static wear leveling* on wikipedia's [wear leveling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling) page.

Typical erase cycles are 10k-10M for a flash chip.  So typically, a flash file system should *level* the erases within +/- 1k for all sectors.  Most disks have long lived data and short lived data.  Hopefully, this explains the need to move long lived data.

Additionally, many flash file system support compression.  When you are appending, you should try to keep your *chunks* to a maximum of the **sector** size or the compression block size.  From a C++ layer, this will naturally be buffered in memory at the task level.  You might set your *stream* buffer size to match and/or only call `flush()` when you are certain a full sector has been written.  The issue with writing a partial sector (or compression block) is that this will leave many partial writes until a full erase block is filled.  Then all of the partial writes will be erased.

You don't have to pay attention to this at the application level, but altering your logging like this can significantly extend the life of the flash.  Of course everything is somewhat dependent on the flash file system.  Not all of them will move the *static data* to ensure **erase** wear leveling.  They may only preform wear leveling on the *free area*; or un-used flash space.

Comment: Some of the information applies to normal hard drives.  It is not good to write partial clusters continuously.  Often there are many buffers in hardware and the OS to try and prevent this.  However, application programs can call things like `fsync()`, etc to undo this and cause additional wear.  For some files this is needed.  I would avoid this for logging.

Comment: I only need to keep a year's worth of data, and it won't be even close to filling up an MMC card. I was thinking of implementing some scheme where the log would be spread out in "chunk files". After a year's worth of data has been logged, the oldest chunk file would be erased before a new one is created. This should prevent the erase wear levelling problem you described.

Comment: It won't be possible for me to flush only when a full sector has to be written. I'm only logging ~100 bytes of data every 1 minute. Assuming a 4k sector size, it would take roughly an hour before I'd have enough data to flush, and I don't want to risk losing that data because of a power failure. I suppose I could maintain a backup of the current "bucket" in some kind of non-volatile RAM, but I think that would be overkill. :-)

Comment: Your *MMC* card may already have facilities to do static wear leveling.  Mainly I was talking about NAND flash with a direct BUS interface; but an MMC card is basically the same with a separate controller that does all this stuff in hardware/firmware.  It is true that you may already have enough life-time; when I did calculation for our system, the application needs to write every few milliseconds for 10 years to wear out the flash (in theory).  The LCD on this device will wear out before that.  But I think the extra information is good as not all FLASH chips and products have the same lifes.